# Subset Data Based On Elements In List

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

In `R`, I am trying to subset the `data.frame` named `Data`  by using element stored in a `list`.

**Data**

```
Data <- read.table(text = "  Data_x  Data_y  Column_X 
                                -34      12       A
                                -36      20       D
                                -36      12       E
                                -34      18       F
                                -34      10       B
                                -35      24       A
                                -35      16       B
                                -33      22       B
                                -33      14       C
                                -35      22       D", header = T)
```

**Code**

```
variableData <- list("A", "B")
subsetData_1 <- subset(Data, Column_X == variableData[1])
subsetData_2 <- subset(Data, Column_X == variableData[2])
subsetData <- rbind(subsetData_1, subsetData_2)
```

**Problems**

- First, the elements in the `list` can be more than two and is not fixed. Can even have more than 100 elements.
- Second, I want to keep only one `data.frame` which will store all the subset data extracted using all the elements in `list`. If there are more elements, lets say 100, then I don't want to repeat `subset()` for each of the elements.

Is there a better way to approach this than the code above? As my approach is not good enough and will take performance hit.

Any suggestion will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: You might want to read the warning in `?subset`. It is not meant to be used when writing programs.

Comment: @Frank - You scared me: `?subset` says `subset can have unanticipated consequences`. Can you please point me to an example?

Comment: Sure. Here's a Q&A on it https://stackoverflow.com/q/9860090/ Tbh, I did not read it carefully and simply remembered to avoid coding with `subset`, so I'm not really an authority on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic `lapply`.

```
x <- lapply(variableData, function(x){subset(Data, Column_X == x)})
x
# [[1]]
# Data_x Data_y Column_X
# 1    -34     12        A
# 6    -35     24        A
# 
# [[2]]
# Data_x Data_y Column_X
# 5    -34     10        B
# 7    -35     16        B
# 8    -33     22        B
```

it returns a list of all the subsets. To `rbind` all these list elements just

```
do.call(rbind, x)
#   Data_x Data_y Column_X
# 1    -34     12        A
# 6    -35     24        A
# 5    -34     10        B
# 7    -35     16        B
# 8    -33     22        B
```

however, as @Frank pointed out, you could use basic subsetting in your code:

```
Data[Data$Column_X %in% variableData,]
#   Data_x Data_y Column_X
# 1    -34     12        A
# 5    -34     10        B
# 6    -35     24        A
# 7    -35     16        B
# 8    -33     22        B
```

> "Warning
>
> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences." (`?subset`)

Furthermore, thus the order of your rows will be kept.

Answer (score 10):

`%in%` should do the trick:

```
subset(Data, Column_X %in% variableData)
```

You can also use `dplyr` and filter:

```
Data %>% filter(Column_X %in% variableData)
```

Comment: This might require variableData be a vector (instead of the list the OP used). I think the OP should use a vector, anyways.

Comment: @Frank - That question even I had whether to use `list()` or `vector()`. For my problem, I should stick to `variableData <- c("A", "B")`