# Using lapply to subset a dataframe based on two or more factor variables

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, apply

This is an extension of the StackOverflow question - [Subset Data Based On Elements In List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360423/subset-data-based-on-elements-in-list) - which answered the problem of how to create a list of new dfs, each being constructed by subsetting the original one based on a grouping factor variable.

The challenge I am encountering is that i need to create the dfs using more than one grouping variable

To generalise the problem, I have created this toy dataset - which has as the response variable the daily amount of rain, and as classifiers the temperature range and the cloudiness of that day.

```
rain <- c(2, 0, 4, 25, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 0, 8, 35)
temp <- as.factor(c("Warm","Cold","Hot","Cold","Warm","Cold","Cold","Warm","Warm","Hot","Cold", "Cold"))
clouds <- as.factor(c("Some","Lots","None","Lots","None","None","Lots","Some","Some","Lots","None", "Some"))
df <- data.frame(rain, temp, clouds)
```

With the following code, i can produce three new dataframes grouped on the temp variable, all combined into a single list (df_1A):

```
temp_levels <- unique(as.character(df$temp))
df_1A <- lapply(temp_levels, function(x){subset(df, temp == x)})
```

And ditto for three new dataframes grouped by the cloudiness

```
cloud_levels <- unique(as.character(df$clouds))
df_1B <- lapply(cloud_levels, function(x){subset(df, clouds == x)})
```

However, I have not been able to come up with a simple, elegant way to produce the 9 dataframes each of which has a unique combination of temp and cloudiness

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `split` to divide data based on unique levels of `temp` and `clouds`.

```
df_1 <- split(df, list(df$temp, df$clouds))
```

Comment: This is just the solution i was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies a preference for `lapply` but if you don't mind using `dplyr` there is an elegant solution.

```r
library(dplyr)

df_list <- 
   df %>% 
   group_by(temp, clouds) %>% 
   group_split()

# df_list

df_list[[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    rain temp  clouds
#>   <dbl> <fct> <fct> 
#> 1     0 Cold  Lots  
#> 2    25 Cold  Lots  
#> 3     4 Cold  Lots
```

Your data

```r
rain <- c(2, 0, 4, 25, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 0, 8, 35)
temp <- as.factor(c("Warm","Cold","Hot","Cold","Warm","Cold","Cold","Warm","Warm","Hot","Cold", "Cold"))
clouds <- as.factor(c("Some","Lots","None","Lots","None","None","Lots","Some","Some","Lots","None", "Some"))
df <- data.frame(rain, temp, clouds)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I am not yet at the stage of fully embracing the tidyverse way of data analysis - thus I have given the tick to the reply that used core R. However, I am sure that for those who prefer dplyr solutions, yours will be a very useful reply.